# Accounting Terminology

Tags: phrase-choice

I would like to know how to say something related to accounting in English.

I have to show the totals of a current account in the following way:

**Totals: Below all, show the total Credit, Debit and Balance in favor of Supplier or My Company.**

(this was translated by google. I do not know if it's correct in English but I think you get to understand).

Then I put it like that

> "totals": {
>           "debit": 2200,
>           "credit": 1100.5,
>           "balance": 1099.5,
>           "in_favor_to": "Supplier"
>       }

Is it correct to say: "in_favor_to"
or is there a specific term of accounting for referise to is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the above it would be more common to say "In relationship to". These calculations of credits and debit explain the relationship between your company and your supplier. If the number is positive it would explain the amount your company owes the supplier. If the number is negative it would show the amount of money your supplier owes your company.

The use of "favor" insinuates a positive correlation between the supplier and your company regardless of the numbers calculated. Where "relationship" indicates a neutral correlation between the two based on text and lets the numbers dictate whether it is positive or negative.

Comment: Aha, I understand ... it would not be common the resulting number (balance in this case) always be positive and the text be the one defining to who is positive. But making an exception, if the manager wants the number be shown always positive and the text be that defines for which company. It would be correct to say "$ 1000 In relationship to Supplier/MyCompany"?

Comment: In the case that the number is always positive you could use favor or relationship or in some wordings both. A sample sentence would be "The relationship between the supplier and our company is in favor by $1000".